# How I can access to package.json config section?

Tags: node.js, config

As I can see in https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html one way to expose config section of *package.json* to environment variables is use `npm start` command.

I found modules that loads *package.json* file as JSON and export *config* property after that. But the easiest way is define all configuration as module and `require` it on demand. Am I right? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also load the entire `package.json` as a module with `require('./package')` and the entire JSON object will be that module's `exports`, so you can do `console.log(require('./package').version);`, for example.

Comment: @VladimirKuznetsov can you accept this answer then, please? That way people won't read the question unnecessarily plus I get delicious reputation points.

Comment: Would it be bad form to include initialization properties in the package data?  If(package.unpack){ package.unpack = false; fs.mkdir(package.outputFolder); }

Comment: I think package.json is already overloaded for too many purposes. Files are free. Use a different file.